# asynchroneous error handling and response processing of an unbounded list of tasks using zeep

Tags: python, error-handling, concurrency, python-asyncio, zeep

So here is my use case:

- I read from a database rows containing information to make a complex SOAP call (I'm using zeep to do these calls).
- One row from the database corresponds to a request to the service.
- There can be up to 20 thousand lines, so I don't want to read everything in memory before making the calls.
- I need to process the responses - when the
  response is OK, I need to store some returned information back into
  my database, and when there is an exception I need to process the
  exception for that particular request/response pair.
- I need also to capture some external information at the time of the request creation, so that I know where to store the response from the request. In my current code I'm using the delightful property of gather() that makes the results come in the same order.

I read the relevant PEPs and Python documentation but I'm still very confused, as there seems to be multiple ways to solve the same problem.

I also went through countless exercises on the web, but the examples are all trivial - it's either asyncio.sleep() or some webscraping with a finite list of urls.

The solution that I have come up so far kinda works - the asyncio.gather() method is very, very, useful, but I have not been able to 'feed' it from a generator. I'm currently just counting to an arbitrary size and then starting a .gather() operation. I've transcribed the code, with boring parts left out and I've tried to anonymise the code

I've tried solutions involving semaphores, queues, different event loops, but I'm failing every time. Ideally I'd like to be able to create Futures 'continuously' - I think I'm missing the logic of 'convert this awaitable call to a future'

I'd be grateful for any help!

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import Future

import zeep
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin


history = HistoryPlugin()

max_concurrent_calls = 5

provoke_errors = True

def export_data_async(db_variant: str, order_nrs: set):
    st = time.time()
    results = []

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


    def get_client1(service_name: str, system: Systems = Systems.ACME) -> Tuple[zeep.Client, zeep.client.Factory]:
        client1 = zeep.Client(wsdl=system.wsdl_url(service_name=service_name),
                              transport=transport,
                              plugins=[history],
                              )
        factory_ns2 = client1.type_factory(namespace='ns2')

        return client1, factory_ns2

    table = 'ZZZZ'
    moveback_table = 'EEEEEE'
    moveback_dict = create_default_empty_ordered_dict('attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute3')

    client, factory = get_client1(service_name='ACMEServiceName')

    if log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        client.wsdl.dump()
        zeep_log = logging.getLogger('zeep.transports')
        zeep_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    with Db(db_variant) as db:

        db.open_db(CON_STRING[db_variant])

        db.init_table_for_read(table, order_list=order_nrs)        

        counter_failures = 0

        tasks = []
        sids = []
        results = []

        def handle_future(future: Future) -> None:
            results.extend(future.result())

        def process_tasks_concurrently() -> None:
            nonlocal tasks, sids, counter_failures, results

            futures = asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
            futures.add_done_callback(handle_future)
            loop.run_until_complete(futures)
            for i, response_or_fault in enumerate(results):
                if type(response_or_fault) in [zeep.exceptions.Fault, zeep.exceptions.TransportError]:
                    counter_failures += 1
                    log_webservice_fault(sid=sids[i], db=db, err=response_or_fault, object=table)
                else:

                    db.write_dict_to_table(
                        moveback_table,
                        {'sid': sids[i],
                         'attribute1': response_or_fault['XXX']['XXX']['xxx'],
                         'attribute2': response_or_fault['XXX']['XXX']['XXXX']['XXX'],
                         'attribute3': response_or_fault['XXXX']['XXXX']['XXX'],
                         }
                    )
            db.commit_db_con()
            tasks = []
            sids = []
            results = []
            return

        for row in db.rows(table):
            if int(row.id) % 2 == 0 and provoke_errors:
                payload = faulty_message_payload(row=row,
                                                 factory=factory,
                                                 )
            else:
                payload = message_payload(row=row,
                                          factory=factory,
                                          )

            tasks.append(client.service.myRequest(
                MessageHeader=factory.MessageHeader(**message_header_arguments(row=row)),
                myRequestPayload=payload,
                _soapheaders=[security_soap_header],
            ))
            sids.append(row.sid)
            if len(tasks) == max_concurrent_calls:
                process_tasks_concurrently()

        if tasks:  # this is the remainder of len(db.rows) % max_concurrent_calls
            process_tasks_concurrently()

        loop.run_until_complete(transport.session.close())

        db.execute_this_statement(statement=update_sql)
        db.commit_db_con()

        log.info(db.activity_log)
        if counter_failures:
            log.info(f"{table :<25} Count failed: {counter_failures}")

        print("time async: %.2f" % (time.time() - st))
    return results
```

Failed attempt with Queue: (blocks at `await client.service`)

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

counter = 0
results = []

async def payload_generator(db_variant: str, order_nrs: set):
    

    # code that generates the data for the request

    yield counter, row, payload


async def service_call_worker(queue, results):
    while True:
        counter, row, payload = await queue.get()
        results.append(await client.service.myServicename(
            MessageHeader=calculate_message_header(row=row)),
            myPayload=payload,
            _soapheaders=[security_soap_header],
        )
                       )
        print(colorama.Fore.BLUE + f'after result returned {counter}')


        # Here do the relevant processing of response or error
        queue.task_done()


async def main_with_q():
    n_workers = 3
    queue = asyncio.Queue(n_workers)
    e = pprint.pformat(queue)
    p = payload_generator(DB_VARIANT, order_list_from_args())
    results = []
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(service_call_worker(queue, results))
               for _ in range(n_workers)]

    async for c in p:
        await queue.put(c)

    await queue.join()  # wait for all tasks to be processed
    for worker in workers:
        worker.cancel()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main_with_q())
        loop.run_until_complete(transport.session.close())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Queues are likely the way to go. Can you show the queue-based solution that failed to work?

Comment: Sure I’ll post it tomorrow. Not my finest code though.

Comment: BTW `run_until_complete()` returns the result of the future it runs, so you can replace the add/done_callback/handle_future logic with the simpler `results.extend(loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(...)))`

Comment: Another question: why is `export_data_async` not - async? The modern way to use asyncio is to avoid `run_until_complete`, but to have a single async entry point (by convention called `main`, but you can name it anything you want), and run it with `asyncio.run(main())`. Is there a reason why you went for multiple runs of the event loop?

Comment: That’s because the initialising of the zero client object is synchronous (wsdl retrieval).

Comment: But you could still have one async entry point and use `asyncio.run()` to execute it, no?

Comment: @user4815162342 that was the only clunky way I found to limit the amount of simultaneous calls. That’s the bit I find ugly.